# How to kill a ghost process? AIX 6.1

Tags: process, aix

oslevel: 6100-05-01-1016

according to topas:

```
root    1769602       1  93 20   112     0   128 32498:07 87.1    0    0 ldmp_pro
```

according to ps:

```
-bash-4.1# ps -ef | egrep -i "1769602|ldmp"
    root  9502842 22806540   1 13:24:32 pts/17  0:00 egrep -i 1769602|ldmp 
-bash-4.1#
```

kill:

```
-bash-4.1# kill -9 1769602
-bash-4.1#
```

and it keeps going in topas/nmon, but i still can't see it in ps.. :D

How can I kill the "ldmp_pro"? It consumes a lot of CPU..

Comment: `kill -9` should not be used unless it's a shell. Before that try SIGTERM or SIGSEGV (I can't remember the decimal values for AIX).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you caused the high CPU load by sending it a signal. It is a kernel process, and there's an APAR for this issue: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IZ97168
Be advised that the Ifix requires a reboot, as the fix is for the kernel.
And as it's a kernel processes you cannot kill that process.

For completeness, the full name of the process is `ldmp_process`.